# Solution to a nonlinear PDE

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

A stochastic control problem has led me to the following PDE:

State space: $t \in [0,T]$ and $x \in [-1,1]$.

$$4 \frac{\partial f}{\partial t} \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} = 1 \quad \forall (t,x) \in [0,T) \times (-1,1)$$
and the boundary conditions are: 
$$
\begin{split}
  f(T,x) &= 0\quad \forall x\\
        &\text{and} \\
f(t,\pm 1) &= T-t
\end{split}$$
Is there an argument that can let me say that a solution exists to this PDE? I am not after a closed form expression obviously.

From the properties of the problem I can argue that $f(t,x) = f(t,-x)$ and $\arg \max_x f(t,x) = 0$. Don't know if it is of any use though.

Thanks.

Comment: By inspection, $f(t,x) = (T-t)(9-x^2)/8$ is a solution.

Comment: Not sure I see it. The right hand side of the PDE is 1, not $f$. If we evaluate the left hand side with your expression we have $-(T-t)(9-x^2)=-8f(t,x)$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @StanleySnelson: the initial condition $f(T,x)=0$ for all $x$ implies that, if $f$ is $C^2$ near $t=T$, then $f_{xx}=0$. But the equation gives $4f_tff_{xx}=1$, a contradiction. So there is no $C^2$ solution, with the given boundary conditions.

Comment: Not sure I agree entirely. I follow that $f_{xx} \to 0$ as $t \to T$. However, we could have $f_t \to \infty$ at the same time to have $f$ being $C^{1,2}$ on $(0,T) \times (-1,1)$, isn't it?

Comment: @avk255: I was thinking of $f$ being $C^2$ on $[0,T]\times[-1,1]$, like Stanley Snelson's solution. As you say, you must have some blow up of $f_t$.

Comment: At least formally, taking the Legendre transform $u$ of $f$ in the $x$ variable, we have that $w := u(x, T-t)$ solves the heat equation. Taking initial data $w(x,0) = |x|$ and transforming back gives a nontrivial solution with $0$ data on the sides. It seems feasible that playing with the initial data for $w$ could give a solution with the desired data (which corresponds to $w_{xx} = 1$ where $w_x = \pm 1$).

Comment: @ConnorMooney Many thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't know anything about Legendre transforms for me to understand exactly. Do you have any link where I can read this up? Thanks!

Comment: Roughly, taking the Legendre transform inverts the second derivative. The book of Evans on PDE has a nice section on Legendre transform. A recent book of Figalli on the Monge-Ampere equation is another good reference, which also discusses the partial Legendre transform (where you take it in only one variable, as I suggest above).

Comment: Thanks! Will check.

Answer (score 1):

Putting $T=1$, I obtain with Maple:

```
sol := pdsolve(4*(diff(f(t, x), t))*(diff(f(t, x), x, x)) = 1,
 {f(1, x) = 0, f(t, -1) = 1-t, f(t, 1) = 1-t}, numeric):sol:-plot3d(t = 0 .. 1, x = -1 .. 1);
```

> solution becomes undefined, problem may be ill posed or method may be ill suited to solution

Comment: Mathematica reports "NDSolve::ndnum: Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at t == 1."

Comment: My sense is that, in light of what Ben pointed out above, we must have a blowup for $f_t$ near $T$. That maybe the reason why numerical solutions are showing non existence?